# SQL 2008 Dialect Support for NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, sql-server-2008

Is anyone working on or know if there exists a SQL 2k8 Dialect for NHibernate?

Comment: This page has some information on the subject: [NHibernate and Ms Sql Server 2008: Date, Time, DateTime2 and DateTimeOffset](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/11/nhibernate-and-ms-sql-server-2008-date-time-datetime2-and-datetimeoffset.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was [asked on the NHibernate Google Group recently](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/de3d59012cd5835b/50c50677b250f97b) - apparently the SQL 2005 dialect should work against SQL 2008.

Definitive location of the dialects - source control is [here](https://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Dialect/), binary downloads are [here](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=73818).

Answer (score 8):

The MsSql2008Dialect is available [here](https://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Dialect/).

Fabio Mulo has just released the [Beta1 of NHibernate 2.1](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/06/07/nhibernate-2-1-0beta1.aspx#359) that should come with the MsSql2008Dialect and [support the new DateTime datatypes](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/11/nhibernate-and-ms-sql-server-2008-date-time-datetime2-and-datetimeoffset.aspx), but i didn't saw anything regarding the other datatypes. Anyway, the Beta1 seems to really good, I am testing it and look good.