# Does NHibernate support MsSql2008? Can it convert SQL XML DataType to XElement properties?

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

I couldn't find an answer - does NHibernate supports MsSql2008? For example - can it convert sql XML data type to .NET XElement?

MsSqlConfiguration. shows only MsSql2005, MsSql2000 and MsSql7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first question was answered here: [SQL 2008 Dialect Support for NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889/sql-2008-dialect-support-for-nhibernate)

As for XElement I'm not sure, but it wouldn't be hard to implement as a customer IUserType.

Comment: Ben, i would be glad if you could check out this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852444/nhibernate-sproc-output-parameter  
  
This is quite crucial for paging implementation. Or maybe there are other ways how it's done?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a [new Sql 2008 dialect in the latest Alpha of NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/11/nhibernate-and-ms-sql-server-2008-date-time-datetime2-and-datetimeoffset.aspx) but as far as I know this is to support some of the new Date types available in SQL Server 2008.  As far as I know support for the SQL XML type is still not included for the reasons Ben has already pointed out.

Comment: Well... He didn't point out for me. I'm just starting to learn it, no ideas about common techniques.